# Python global variables demo

Tags: python-2.7

```
wcyear = 2000
def worldcup():
    global wcyear
    for i in wcyear:
        wcyear = wcyear+4
        print wcyear

print 'world cup year: ',wcyear
worldcup()
print 'Out of function wc year: ',wcyear
```

error what am getting is :`TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`
is global variables are are not supported in loops?

Comment: The issue is that you are trying to loop over an integer, and not, for instance a list. Try: `for i in 4:  print(i)` vs `for i in [4]:  print(i)` to see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

your wcyear variable is an integer which can't be iterated by for loop. In place of that you can use below logic:

```
for i in range(0,wcyear):
```

if you need to start from 0 other wise you can use **range(1,wcyear)**.

Answer (score 0):

global variables are supported. In order to use a `for` loop, you need to *iterate* over *iterable* object.

In your case, wcyear is **an int**. int isn't iterable.

> [**iterable**](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterable) :
>   An object capable of returning its members one at a time. Examples of iterables include all sequence types (such as list, str, and tuple) and some non-sequence types like dict and file and objects of any classes you define with an **iter**() or **getitem**() method. Iterables can be used in a for loop and in many other places where a sequence is needed (zip(), map(), …).

If your global variable was a list, eg `wcyear = [2000]` or a tuple `wcyear = (2000,)` it would work.